# Parse Push Notifications Very Slow

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I'm sending Push Notifications with Parse, and they're very slow right now, up to 5 minutes to receive a push. I've looked on the Push Dashboard, and they're stuck in the Pending state, so it appears to be an issue with the Parse Push system.

I've been using Parse Push notifications for a while, and usually I receive the notifications in a couple seconds. This seems like it's an issue.

Is anyone else having the same issue with Parse Push? Can someone from Parse look into this?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: The Parse Developers Google group is a better place to ask this question https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers. You can also file a bug report at parse.com/help if this is an ongoing issue for you.